# jquery to execute and change the picture after button's click event finished executing?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a pic and a button in the same page. On clicking that button Backup is being taken. I want to change the picture after the button event is over. Any jQuery that will be suitable for this purpose, and that will execute after button's click event is over

Comment: I don't get it, why do you mean when button's click event is over? Why don't you just change the picture using `.click()` function of jQuery?

Comment: hi GoRoS actually its a project requirement. I can either do it in a simple way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.RegisterClientScriptBlock`

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
Type cstype = this.GetType();

if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(cstype, "script block name"))
{
    StringBuilder cstext2 = new StringBuilder();
    cstext2.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
    cstext2.Append("$('#image').attr('src','/new_image.png'); </");
    cstext2.Append("script>");
    cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, "script block name", cstext2.ToString(), false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<img src="/your_image.png" id="image">

<button id="backup">Backup</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#backup').click(function()
{
    /* ajax call */
    $.post('/backup.php',function()
    {
        /* after the ajax call has been executed it changes the image */
        $('#image').attr('src','/new_image.png');
    });
});
```

**Manual:** [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)